# Loop Through Results from a Method

Tags: c#

I have a method that calls a Proc ad returns the data. But I want to call the method and loop through all the results and use the results to plug into an Excel document. I can't seem to figure out how to loop through results coming from the method call. This is my method:

```
    public DataView GetCoupons()
    {
        string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CPC_GetAllCoupons", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        //make the dap & ds
        SqlDataAdapter dap = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        //open con
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            conn.Open();

        //get the data
        dap.Fill(ds);

        //close the conn and return
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            conn.Close();

        return ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
   }
```

So I want to call that method and get all the results and loop through the results. How would I go about doing that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, *should* be enough

```
foreach (DataRowView rowView in dv) //where dv is your DataView
{
    DataRow row = rowView.Row;

    // Do your stuff here
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

When you fill a `DataSet`, you get a representation of all the result sets returned from the procedure call. To access individual result sets, you simply enumerate over the `Tables` collection like you are doing:

```
 foreach(DataTable table in ds.Tables)
```

Then, you can enumerate through all the records in each dataset like so:

```
 foreach(DataRow row in table.Rows)
```

And then get data from each record:

```
 object something = row["SomeColumnName"];
```

Comment: thanks, would I put the call to the method that returns the DataTable were the ds.Tables is in the foreach?

Comment: I was pulling the variable names from your code; where you were executing `return ds.Tables[0].DefaultView`, you could instead just `return ds;` and then in your calling code, perform the enumerations and do what you need to do as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

```
DataView coupons = GetCoupons();
foreach (var row in coupons) {
   // do something here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend encapsulating the data access in a repository which returns objects of a type which you require. E.g.

```
public class Coupon
{
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public int Bar { get; set; }
}

public class CouponRepository
{
    private readonly string connectionString;

    public CouponRepository(string connectionString)
    {
        this.connectionString = connectionString;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Coupon> GetCoupons()
    {        
        using(var conn = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString))
        using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("CPC_GetAllCoupons", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            conn.Open();

            using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    yield return new Coupon
                    {
                        Foo = (int)reader["Foo"],
                        Bar = (int)reader["Bar"],
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:-

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SiteSqlServer"].ConnectionString;
var repo = new CouponRepository(connectionString);
foreach (var coupon in repo.GetCoupons())
{
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
Dataview dv = GetCoupons();
foreach(Item item in dv.Table.Rows)
{
    //...
}
```

But there is a lot of ways of doing this.